# Apache and MySQL taking all the memory? Maximum connections?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, memory, connection, dedicated-server

I've a had one of our servers going down (network wise) but keeping its uptime (so looks the server is not losing its power) recently. I've asked my hosting company to investigate and I've been told, after investigation, that Apache and MySQL were at all time using 80% of the memory and peaking at 95% and that I might  be needing to add some more RAM to the server.

One of their justifications to adding more RAM was that I was using the default max connections setting (125 for MySQL and 150 for Apache) and that for handling those 150 simultaneous connections, I would need at least 3GB of memory instead of the 1GB I have at the moment.

Now, I understand that tweaking the max connections might be better than me leaving the default setting although I didn't feel it was a concern at the moment, having had servers with the same configuration handle more traffic than the current 1 or 2 visitors before the launch, telling myself I'd tweak it depending on the visits pattern later.

I've also always known Apache was more memory hungry under default settings than its competitor such as nginx and lighttpd. Nonetheless, looking at the stats of my machine, I'm trying to see how my hosting company got those numbers.

I'm getting:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1000        944         56          0        148        725
-/+ buffers/cache:         71        929
Swap:         1953          0       1953
```

Which I guess means that yes, the server is reserving around 95% of its memory at the moment but I also thought it meant that only 71 out of the 1000 total were really used by the applications at the moment looking a the buffers/cache row.

Also I don't see any swapping:

```
# vmstat 60
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0      0  57612 151704 742596    0    0     1     1    3   11  0  0 100  0
 0  0      0  57604 151704 742596    0    0     0     1    1   24  0  0 100  0
 0  0      0  57604 151704 742596    0    0     0     2    1   18  0  0 100  0
 0  0      0  57604 151704 742596    0    0     0     0    1   13  0  0 100  0
```

And finally, while requesting a page:

```
top - 08:33:19 up 3 days, 13:11,  2 users,  load average: 0.06, 0.02, 0.00
Tasks:  81 total,   1 running,  80 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  1.3%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.3%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   1024616k total,   976744k used,    47872k free,   151716k buffers
Swap:  2000052k total,        0k used,  2000052k free,   742596k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND           
24914 www-data  20   0 26296 8640 3724 S    2  0.8   0:00.06 apache2            
23785 mysql     20   0  125m  18m 5268 S    1  1.9   0:04.54 mysqld             
24491 www-data  20   0 25828 7488 3180 S    1  0.7   0:00.02 apache2            
    1 root      20   0  2844 1688  544 S    0  0.2   0:01.30 init               
...
```

So, I'd like to know, experts of serverfault:

1. Do I really need more RAM at the moment? **// Update: I'd really like to understand why they say I'm using all my current RAM and how to justify the RAM bump they recommend.**
2. How do they calculate that for 150 simultaneous connections I'd need 3GB?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are you running..  mod_perl, PHP?

Comment: Good question, I've forgotten to add I'm running PHP5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the snapshot here, the memory utilization seems fine and an upgrade wouldn't be necessary (and probably wouldn't help).

Free & top both state that there is just ~50 MB or so free, but when accounting for buffers, that number is significantly higher. Linux is going to use any unallocated/unused physical RAM as cache & buffer space. If your applications need more memory, brk & sbrk will yank it from cache. There are performance implications as that happens more frequently, but that's probably not a concern here at all.

Now, it's very possible that you're indeed spiking on occasion during times of high traffic or maintenance script runs.  Do you have any cron jobs scheduled that execute large queries as part of a cleanup process or anything? Is there anything that might swallow up RAM temporarily and then release it? Account freeze batch jobs or anything?

All that said, can you describe your problem a bit more? If you're not able to ping the system, I highly, *highly* doubt it's a memory problem at all.  Does your server just go away for a while and then come back?  Check your web server logs during that period, is there a period of inactivity for everyone, or just you?  If your machine is just falling off of the planet for a period of time, I'd vote that it's something network related.

What about dmesg output? Net device errors?

Comment: That's a fantastic answer. Thanks mcjeff, it confirms what I was thinking. The server goes away for a while and then comes back yes. I've checked the logs when it happened and saw nothing. There is not enough visitors yet to say if we were the only one affected but last time I asked them to verify what happened, they found a faulty network adapter and changed it. This time, they say they didn't find anything faulty on their end except maybe a few error on our switch port that didn't seem recent. That's when they talked about the lacking memory and conntrack table size. Faulty cable possible?

Comment: Faulty cable is possible -- but you just said something else that makes sense, too... "conntrack table size." I've had situations on systems where that has caused the machine to just drop traffic, much like you're seeing.

Though, the cluster I'm referring to was pumping out ~2000 hits/sec.  You probably wouldn't see anything unless you had a lot of IP tables rules or you were doing a tremendous amount of traffic.

You can check, though:

sysctl net.ipv4.netfilter | grep conntrack

Comment: ip_conntrack_count is the number you have, ip_conntrack_max is the total amount possible. Are they close? IF you were dropping packets due to a full connection tracking table, then 'dmesg' would report that. To suggest that on a system doing such a small amount of traffic sounds off to me, though.

Comment: My $10 says it's a network related. Faulty cable, bad NIC, screwy ARP handling on an access switch.

Comment: net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_count = 7, net.ipv4.netfilter.ip_conntrack_max = 1048576... doesn't sound close to me... You are confirming what I thought: a lot of bogus diagnosis even with access to the machine to check that out... I would put another 10$ they changed something else while giving me all this food for thought with a recommendation for RAM upgrade ($). I don't have proof but I found every other diagnosis doubtful with how little traffic we are currently handling on this development machine.

Answer (score 2):

> How do they calculate that for 150 simultaneous connections I'd need 3Gb?

150 * average RAM for a single Apache client (which they've apparently decided is 20 MB for your case).

Comment: And why would they decide it's 20MB by connection? Is this the standard number used for Apache-PHP-MySQL?

Comment: They likely just looked at how much your Apache processes are currently using. `ps aux | grep apache` will show a list of Apache processes and how much RAM each is using. There's no standard figure, as it depends on your modules and the code they're executing.

Answer (score 1):

"the current 1 or 2 visitors before the lunch"

If you have 1-2 visitors the issue isnt max connections and probably not a RAM issue but a configuration issue.
 It can potentialy be Mysql reserved cache RAM for indexes and query caches.

Comment: With the numbers I've given, is it really a memory problem? As I said, I've been running the same config on less memory for more visitors and it's been handling it fine. Would I see something in the logs that would prevent me from connecting with FTP, SSH, HTTP or even pinging the server?

Answer (score 1):

The memory your apache is using depends from php memory usage, from number of loaded apache and php modules and the number of connections.
You always want to check for the worst scenario:
 MEMOF( max php mem,max loaded modules) x max apache connections 
 and you always want to avoid going into the swap so the result should be less than your physical memory amount.
You also have mysql server running so you have to consider it max memory usage as well.
You can do many configuration optimization to reduce the memory usage while keeping your site fast and stable ( do a search in serverfault - here you can find useful discussions).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering though: seeing the numbers I've put in the original question, is it really consuming already 95% of the memory as they are claiming? How do you see what load the current visitors are putting on the server?